# Creating Extension method to include subquery

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, lambda

I am having trouble creating an extension method for an IQueryable that will include the translation for a specified column in a Linq Query.

Suppose i have the query below. 
I would like to call a method IncludeTranslation on the CFG_Article IQueryable specifying the column i want to get the translation for.
Could someone help me in the right direction.

```
var translations = 
    from t in UoW.CFG_TRANSLATION.GetAll()
    select t;

var result = (
    from a in UoW.CFG_ARTICLE.GetAll()
    select new
    {
        a,
        translation = translations
            .Where(t=> t.TR_TEXT == a.AR_NAME).FirstOrDefault()
    });
```

All i have come up so far is the code below but this does not compile.

```
public static IQueryable IncludeTranslation<T>(
        this IQueryable<T> query, 
        Expression<Func<t, bool>> fieldToTranslate)
{
    // this will get an IQueryable of CFG_TRANSLATION
    var translations = GetTranslations(); 

    var result = (
        from q in query
        select new
        {
            q,
            translation = translations
                .Where(t=> t.TR_TEXT == fieldToTranslate)
                .FirstOrDefault()
        });
    // even better is to return all fields from query 
    // + the TR_TRANSLATION field from the translations table

    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found an other way of returning the same result using a Generic Way.

> ```
>     public static IQueryable IncludeTranslation<S>(this IQueryable<S> source, Expression<Func<S, string>> keyField)
>         where S : class
>     {
>         IQueryable<CFG_TRANSLATION> translations = GetTranslations();
>         var trans = source.GroupJoin(translations, keyField, t => t.TR_TEXT, (s, t) => new { Source = s, Translations = t });
>         var result = trans.Select(t => new { 
>             Source = t.Source, 
>             Translation = t.Translations
>                             .FirstOrDefault() 
>         });
>         return result;
>     }
> ```

Maybe someone can use this as a sollution

this can be called as follow

> var Result = QueryableTable.IncludeTranslation(t => t.FieldToTranslate);

Answer (score 1):

Try this (I'm having to guess class names are CFG_ARTICLE & CFG_TRANSLATION - replace as required)

```
public static IQueryable IncludeTranslation(
            this IQueryable<CGF_ARTICLE> query, 
            Func<CFG_ARTICLE, CFG_TRANSLATION, bool> fieldToTranslate)
{
    var translations = GetTranslations();

    var result =
        from a in query
        select new
        {
            a,
            translation = translations
                .Where(t => fieldToTranslate(a, t))
                .FirstOrDefault()
        };

    return result;
}
```

calling like this

```
var result = query.IncludeTranslation(
    (article, translation) => article.TR_TEXT == translation.AR_NAME);
```

Comment: Hello qujck, 
Can you tell me how i should invoke this method. 
I mean what should i fill in for the fieldToTranslate parameter. 

the field from the translation table should be compared to the field from IQueryable<T>

Comment: Hi qujck, Thank you for you answer. With you example i now can compile but i get an error at runtime. The LINQ expression node type 'Invoke' is not supported in LINQ to Entities. This is probably because entity framework can't translate the func into a sql statement. Any suggestions?

Comment: @Salako I think you may be out of luck :-(